# What is SFRM_Materialize_Preferred and how can it be used to write more performant functions?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

[Researching this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/301920/2639), I see there is a value for `SetFunctionReturnMode` called `SFRM_Materialize_Preferred`. What is this? Can this be used to write more performant  functions?

There are multiple occurrances of [`SRFM_Materialize` in `contrib/`](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Apostgres+SFRM_Materialize+contrib%2F&type=code) but [none of `SRFM_Materalize_Preferred`](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Apostgres+SFRM_Materialize_Preferred+contrib%2F&type=code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SFRM_Materialize_Preferred`  allows you to write a function that accepts a hint from the caller that can accept `Materialize` or `ValuePerCall` mode [from the documentation in the README](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c30f54ad732ca5c8762bb68bbe0f51de9137dd72/src/backend/utils/fmgr/README)

> Callers that can support both `ValuePerCall` and `Materialize` mode will set `SFRM_Materialize_Preferred`, or not, depending on which mode they prefer.

This is [documented as hint](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/65014000b351d5725eb00d133416ab1b4f8245b1/src/include/nodes/execnodes.h#L283) -- an extension to `SFRM_Materialize` -- in the source,

> `SFRM_Materialize_Random` and `SFRM_Materialize_Preferred` are auxiliary flags about `SFRM_Materialize` mode, rather than separate modes.

You can also see this is used in the [PostgreSQL Function Manager code for SQL `fmgr_sql`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7c337b6b527b7052e6a751f966d5734c56f668b5/src/backend/executor/functions.c#L1019)

```c
lazyEvalOK = !(rsi->allowedModes & SFRM_Materialize_Preferred);
```

## My own Demonstration

I created my own very simplified demonstration of `SFRM_Materialize_Preferred` for the purposes of benchmarking it. You [can see that in my repo for my `pg-srf-repeat`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-srf-repeat-benchmark/blob/main/implementations/materialize_preferred.c). Basically the template boils down to this,

```c
Datum myfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(myfunc);

typedef struct
{
  ; your function state only used in value-per-call mode
} myfunc_fctx;

Datum
myfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  
    ; get variables
    
    if (SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL())
    {
        ReturnSetInfo   *rsinfo       = (ReturnSetInfo *) fcinfo->resultinfo;

        // If we prefer materialize, get it done
        if ( rsinfo->allowedModes & SFRM_Materialize_Preferred ) {

            MemoryContext   per_query_ctx = rsinfo->econtext->ecxt_per_query_memory;
            MemoryContext   oldcontext    = MemoryContextSwitchTo(per_query_ctx);

            Tuplestorestate *tupstore     = tuplestore_begin_heap(false, false, work_mem);
            rsinfo->setResult             = tupstore;
            rsinfo->returnMode            = SFRM_Materialize;
    
            TupleDesc   tupdesc = rsinfo->expectedDesc;

            Datum values[1]             = { ;stuff };
            bool  nulls[sizeof(values)] = {0}; # no nulls

            while ( times-- ) {
                tuplestore_putvalues(tupstore, tupdesc, values, nulls);
            }

            tuplestore_donestoring(tupstore);
            MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);
    
            PG_RETURN_NULL();
        }

        // Initialize for multicall
        else {
            FuncCallContext *funcctx = SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT();
            MemoryContext oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(funcctx->multi_call_memory_ctx);
            myfunc_fctx *fctx = (myfunc_fctx *) palloc(sizeof(myfunc_fctx));

            # set myfunc_fctx
            funcctx->user_fctx = fctx;
            MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);
        }

    }
    
    FuncCallContext *funcctx  = SRF_PERCALL_SETUP();
    myfunc_fctx *fctx         = funcctx->user_fctx;

    # Call this
    SRF_RETURN_NEXT(funcctx, fctx->object);
    # Or this,
    SRF_RETURN_DONE(funcctx);

}
```

This generally seems to perform the faster of `Materialize` or `ValuePerCall` and the overhead of the implementation is minor (as compared to a pure implementation).

## In Pg-Python

**I am maintaining this here because of the overall scarcity of information pertaining.** I have determined that this macro `SRF_SHOULD_MATERIALIZE` case is actually pretty silly [(I've opened up an issue on it)](https://github.com/python-postgres/be/issues/36#issuecomment-959775905); [the problem with the `SRF_SHOULD_MATERIALIZE` macro is `SFRM_Materialize` and `SFRM_ValuePerCall` are always true](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-dump-fcinfo) so essentially it's only ever a slower version of `SFRM_Materialize_Preferred`**

It also seems to be used in the [`pg-python` project which allows you Access Python 3 from PostgreSQL Functions](https://github.com/python-postgres/be/blob/880a5336498ec10ad169034f4badb635e2674065/src/include/pypg/postgres.h), but shy of that there are really [no use cases on all of GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=SFRM_Materialize_Preferred+-README+-execnodes.h+-execSRF.c+-functions.c&type=Code). The `pg-python` macro for [`SRF_SHOULD_MATERIALIZE`](https://github.com/python-postgres/be/blob/880a5336498ec10ad169034f4badb635e2674065/src/include/pypg/postgres.h#L136) is as follows (see above note)

```c
#define SRF_SHOULD_MATERIALIZE(FCINFO) (
  (
    ((ReturnSetInfo *) FCINFO->resultinfo)->allowedModes & SFRM_Materialize
  )
  && (
    !(
      ((ReturnSetInfo *) FCINFO->resultinfo)->allowedModes & SFRM_ValuePerCall
    )
    || ((
      ((ReturnSetInfo *) FCINFO->resultinfo)->allowedModes & SFRM_Materialize_Preferred
    ))
  )
)
```

You can see the [`SRF_SHOULD_MATERIALIZE` macro used once at the call site](https://github.com/python-postgres/be/blob/880a5336498ec10ad169034f4badb635e2674065/src/pl.c#L1656)